# Adding multiple icons to a pushpin with Bing maps api v8

Tags: javascript, svg, maps, bing-maps, pushpin

Bing maps v8 - I am trying to represent more than one icon/symbol at a particular location in the map.

For example, at a particular location, i want to have a pushpin that denotes the location plus I want to have another icon/symbol below the pushpin which represents the severity of the location say (highly crowded - red, moderately crowded - yellow, and less crowded - green).

I am not interested in showing this in the pushpin (image) itself, but I want to have it under the pushpin image along with the title of the location.

With version 7 of bing maps, it was possible to add - atleast a border with different color for puspin image which would satisfy my requirement, but in v8 bing maps it is not possible to add custom CSS/HTML.

Also I want the puspin to be draggable. There are HTMLPushpins but they do not supply proper dragging of pushpin.

Any help at the earliest or need more info? Thanks in advance!

A sample image : As you see the markup in the following link works, but it just does not work in bing maps I dont know why!

```
`https://jsfiddle.net/BalakrishnanE/19z7rd1h/#&togetherjs=NwAKHyPv9G`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I highly recommend taking a look at using SVG templates for pushpins. This will allow you to easily change the color using the shapes color option. Here is a tool that provides some examples of different SVG pushpin templates: http://bingmapsv8samples.azurewebsites.net/#SVG%20Pushpin%20Maker

If you can provide a screenshot of the pushpin you want to create, I can see if I can put together an SVG template that matches it.

Comment: Attached a sample image to my question.. I also have the SVG markup for the attached image.. but it is not just working in bing maps I duno why.. but i can successfully load that image in w3schools editor...

Comment: The issue is that your SVG contains a link to an external image. In order to render an SVG on the HTML5 canvas it is loaded via an image tag and drawn on the canvas. This process happens faster than the external image will load. To get around this, take the external image and turn it into a data uri and put that in the href property of your svg.Here is a simple tool to convert the image online, simply drag and drop it. http://www.cssportal.com/image-to-data/ Now the image you are using is fairly large, but basic. It might make more sense to convert it into pure SVG as it would be a lot smaller

Comment: thanks @rbrundritt !! Understood!! I was now able to almost get what I wanted.. This is ok for now and I hope I can solve things like these that comes up in future!! But if I any issues are faced, I will post a comment.. Thanks for your help!!